# How to combine NavigationDrawerPageSlidingTabStrip with StickyListHeaders Library?

Tags: android, listview

I'm beginner in android. Please, could you me explain how to combine Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip library with StickyListHeaders library. I need to load a listview( StickyListHeader) for each page on viewPager.

I'm trying but i get error at logcat: "`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`"

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to add a view to view hierarchy that's already there. Perhaps you inflated a view, found it by id and are trying to add it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Eugen but i've figured out what the problem was inflate mode in PageContentStripFragment Class at the onCreateView method:

```
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        StickyListHeadersListView stickyList = (StickyListHeadersListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        stickyList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        stickyList.setOnHeaderClickListener(this);
        mAdapter = new HeaderListAdapter(getActivity());
        stickyList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```